# Why equillibrium should neccessarily be reached inside an isolated conductor?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electrostatics, quantum-electrodynamics, conductors

Many conclusions made in study of electrostatics of conductor assumes that conductors should necessarily reach equilibrium. The following deductions are made assuming equilibrium is always reached in any shaped conductor

1)Electric field inside conductor is zero
2)Unbalanced Charges reside on surface(proved using Gauss law)

My question: is why wouldn't electron not reach equilibrium and continue to move in search for equilibrium? By this, I mean, why would they necessarily experience net zero force after some time?

Comment: In a superconducting loop, one can have a current which circulates indefinitely.

Comment: "...why wouldn't electron not..." Better to avoid unnecessary double negatives... :)

Comment: I suggest that you expand your question to indicate what information you are seeking, that is not provided in the three answers given. As now you risk attracting downvotes for not doing any effort yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any system is eventually relaxing to *equilibrium*, which is understood as the set of its most probable configurations. For a system interacting with the environment, this usually mean settling to the state with the lowest energy. Thus, electrons in the metal keep moving until they reduce their potential energy, that is until they neutralize the electric field inside the metal.

How exactly this relaxation happen, and how to describe the resulting equilibrium state is the subject of statistical physics (or of thermodynamics, if we accept the view that any system relaxes to equilibrium as a law of the universe, without going into details.)

**Update:**
1.

> The following deductions are made assuming equilibrium is always reached in any shaped conductor
> [...]
> My question: is why wouldn't electron not reach equilibrium and continue to move in search for equilibrium? By this, I mean, why would they necessarily experience net zero force after some time?

Note that we are talking here about an isolated conductor. E.g., if we were talking about a wire connected between the terminals of a battery, the charges in the wire would not reach equilibrium, but would continue to flow through the wire from one terminal to the other. Eventually, the battery would discharge and the current stops - e.g., we do reach equilibrium, but the equilibrium of a bigger system (wire + battery + other possible elements in the circuit.)

2.
I mentioned previously thermodynamic laws. One of them is the law of increase of entropy, which essentially states that the system always moves towards a state of thermodynamic equilibrium. From the point of view of statistical physics (i.e., from the microscopic point of view) it means that the system eventually explores all possible microscopic configurations, and can be found with equal probability in any of them. If we started from a specific configuration (or a set of configurations), then this configuration becomes less probable with time, and for realistic systems this probability becomes vanishingly small.

Finite resistance (i.e., friction) in a conductor means that moving charges transfer their energy to the lattice. The energy thus becomes redistributed between that of the electrons (potential and kinetic) and that of other degrees of freedom (lattice, energy of the random motion of electrons and nuclei, etc.) Having a state in which electrons have any remaining potential energy thus becomes very improbable.

A toy model to convince oneself that en electron in a potential eventually comes to an equilibrium is Newton's equation for a particle in a potential with friction:
$$
m\ddot{x}=-\gamma \dot{x} -\frac{dU(x)}{dx},
$$
where viscous friction term $-\gamma \dot{x}$ models the electric resistance. Solving exactly for a simple potential, e.g., $U(x)=kx^2$ shows that electrons eventually stops at the minimum of this potential. On the other hand, potential $U(x)=Ex$ does not have minimum - it could correspond to a wire connected to the battery, maintaining constant field gradient across the wire.
(Of course, in this simple model I neglect the potential created by electrons themselves.)

Comment: How do we then know that for every such system,there is always a configuration,where electrons are in equillibrium?

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi if electrons keep moving, they keep losing energy, so eventually they stop... unless, there's an energy source, like a battery. There are some exotic cases where the energy loss mechanism is blocked - like in superconductivity.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the free electrons in the conductor. When an external electric field is applied to a conductor, it exerts a force on the free electrons (negative charges) in the conductor. The free electrons, being negatively charged, experience a force in the direction opposite to the electric field. As a result, they move toward the positive end of the external electric field. Till there is an electric field inside the conductor, the electrons will be forced to move to the opposite direction of electric filed. This movement will continue till there is no electric field in the conductor, after which the electrons will not be forced to move.

Similarly, the unbalanced charges will arrange themselves at the surface of the container so that the field inside is zero, because if it is not zero, then the movement of electrons and charges will continue till the field becomes zero.

Answer (score 0):

When studying electro$\bf statics$ it is often the case that only the initial and final state of a system are considered and the details of the transition from one to the other are not considered.
Consideration of the initial and final states does not usually include a detailed analysis of a system on a molecular scale where instantaneous granularity may occur.
Usually the granularity is too small to be observed and so is ignored.
For example, the surface charge density in a region may fluctuate about an average time value, the electric field within a conductor may fluctuate about an average time value, etc.

Comment: is there any study regarding transition from non equillibrium to equillibrium state?

Comment: I am afraid that I am not aware of such studies. I think that [Earnshaw's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earnshaw%27s_theorem) is related to your question.

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi This is a very hot topic for quantum many-body systems called "quantum thermalization". I think you will find some interesting papers from "eigenstate thermalization hypothesis (ETH)", which a review paper can be found here: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6633/aac9f1/meta